# startActivityForResult out an activity

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

How to use startActivityForResult outside an activity context say in a regular java class

EX:
In the main activity, Im calling method of SampleClass. In this method i have to open the device camera and obtain the image and  process it.

The problem is the control is not going to the onActivityResult callback method inside the SampleClass but instead it is going to onActivityResult callback method inside the MainActivity. What am i doing wrong?

I need to be able to handle the image inside Sample Class only. How can i achieve this

Code Snippet

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...

    SampleClass sample = new Sample(this);   
    sample.openCamera();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            syso("INSIDE MAIN ACTIVITY");
        }

        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

}

SAMPLE CLASS:

```
public class SampleClass extends Activity{

private Context context;

public SampleClass(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void openCamera(){
    Intent photoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(photoIntent, 0);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //get the image 
            // process it.

            syso("INSIDE SAMPLE CLASS");
        }

        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

        }
    }
}
```

}

If i run this program, The output on the console is INSIDE MAIN ACTIVITY. What i want is to be able to get INSIDE SAMPLE CLASS as the output.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: show us openCamera();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you open the camera using MainActivity Context!!
sure will triggered onActivityResult() of MainACtivity.

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(photoIntent, 0);
```

see context object = MainActivity check you SimpleClass constructor.

```
public SampleClass(Context context){
// when you call from mainActivity and send **this** it means context = MainActivty
this.context = context;
}
```

if you want SampleClass onActivityResult() triggered there is no way else extends Activity
then call it like normall way ....

```
Intent photoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
context.startActivityForResult(photoIntent, 0);    // context must = SampleClass (); no other way
```

but if you still want to handel image in SimpleClass then follow this code remove extends Activity

in **SimpleClass**

```
public static void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if(requestCode == 0){
     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //get the image 
        // process it.

        syso("INSIDE SAMPLE CLASS");
     }

      if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

      }
   }
}
```

and in you MainActivity class

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    SimpleClass.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

never ever create new object from activity using new key word Adnroid OS will do that for you when you say

```
 Itnent foo = new(context,foo.class);
```

and if you did maybe this means hack Code and android OS.

i hope you understand and hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.. Ill try this.. I understand this is bad programming, but i have to try these hacks because i don't wanna uses intents and activity. I dont know ...may be i need to re-evaluate why i took that decision !

Comment: What prompted you to avoid intents and activity?

Comment: @iZBasit In the main activity, i have some UI elements and a dedicated a section (Relative Layout 100 X 100) of the screen to be controlled by SampleClass (ie) i pass a reference of this section to SampleClass. SampleClass adds the UI inside that section and controls all the interactions within that section. rest of the UI of main activity is not disturbed. If i use Intents will i be able to embed UI elements into Main Activity ?? I dont know how to and hence ended up going for this approach. Is there any better way to achieve this? The ex above is only an illustration, not the real usage

Comment: Is fragments an option ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
 SampleClass sample = new Sample(this);   
sample.openCamera();
```

just use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleClass .class);
```

and write SampleClass onCreate call openCamera().

Hope this will help.

Comment: This means that i have add sampleclass in the manifest. Right ? Im trying to avoid that !

Comment: yes because you created as activity. And only activity who calls startActivityForResult will get call back. in your case its SampleClass.

Comment: You should generally not create Activities using a constructor but using intents as suggested. Because SampleClass is not a validly registered Activity that went through an adequate lifecycle, it is clear why the callback method of your MainActivity is triggered instead. If you want the callback of SampleClass to be triggered, you have to create it using an intent!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I understand your arguments. What im trying to do is make the camera function as a module. What are my options for doing so ?

Comment: You can make separate static functions on some class and call from onActivityresult method. please accept answer if it help you

Comment: @khurram ill get back to you after trying it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. onActivityResuly will be called on that activity, which have ran another activity.

So if you took activity1 instance to run another activity, another activity will call activity1.onActivityResult()